# In which episode does Beerus say "Goku, are you finished?"

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I saw a lot of videos showing Goku is defeated then Beerus screams "Goku, are you finished?"

In which episode does he say this?

Comment: That's a lot of episodes to scan for this one specific line.  Also too, what language is it in?  If it's subbed, then is it a fansub (which aren't accurate)? What about a fan dub?   There's so much to this that I don't know if anyone could reasonably identify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

I think its episode 110 from dragon ball super. The episode where goku first enter the UI form. Beerus says : Goku are you finished?, Because goku was going to lose the fight.